# Inspect windows processes as Admin (Elevated), not bugging the user

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, security, process

I am building a winforms app that inspects processes as part of its routines. I am only getting a few details from the running processes, such as `MainWindowTitle`, `name`, `executible` etc.

I see on some processes this cant be accessed. I know system processes cant be inspected in detail, but it seems like the ones I cant access, being normal processes, happens because they are being run as Administrator.

I run my visual studio as Administrator, and if I don;t run my compiled app as Admin, I simply cant get any details from the Visual Studio process.

On the flip side, with Management Studio for instance, I don't specifically run it as Administrator, but if I don't run my compiled app as Administrator, I cant inspect the Management Studio process.

Does Management Studio somehow run elevated, without bugging me? (That's what I want to accomplish in my own app)

**What I am looking to do so far:**

1. I have looked at the possibility of running my app elevated using a manifest, but I don't want my whole app to force Admin privileges access on to someone that does not like that..
2. Is there a way for only the routine that inspects my processes, to run elevated, but not to bug the user each time that it runs (Several times/minute).
3. Can I run my process inspection routines in a separate thread, and elevate that thread without bugging the user..
4. Can I do something similar to Task Scheduler, where you can specify the admin account to use in the (Run task as) section? This way the user can be prompted for their password (preferably by the system), and not be bothered the next times it runs.

Any ideas on the subject?

Comment: By "Management Studio" did you mean "SQL Server Management Studio"? If yes, then I am not sure if it has sort of silent auto-elevation. I doubt about it, because some debugging features do *not* work until I run it As Administrator (and go through the UAC). On the other hand, inspect its Security tab in Process Explorer – maybe it has some permission there which makes it uninspectable (besides other things the permission does).

Comment: Yes, SQL Management Studio. Thanks, did not think about using process Explorer to have a look.